# How to make a max value in doughnut chart

Tags: chart.js

I am using reactJs and chartjs.

I have the following chart I would like to make :

[image]

I have the following code

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['OK'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Tomatoes',
      data: [12],
      backgroundColor: [
        '#0EA4EA',
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  }, 
  options: {
      legend: {
          display: false
      },
      cutoutPercentage: 80,
      rotation: 0.75 * Math.PI,
      circumference: 1.5 * Math.PI,
      title: {
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom',
      },
      scale: {
          ticks: {
              min: 0,
              max: 150
          }
      }
   }
});
```

But I can't find a way to set the max value of the arc to 150

[here](https://codepen.io/popoleemaster/pen/eYmRvmz)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the area that isn't in Blue:

```
 labels: ['Ok', 'Not Ok'],
 datasets: [{
  label: '# of Tomatoes',
  data: [12, 138],
  backgroundColor: [
    '#0EA4EA',
  ],
  borderWidth: 1
}]
```